# Critical point of a function on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In one differential geometry class I'm taking, a critical point $p$ of a function $f$ on a manifold $(M,\mathcal{A})$ is defined as a point where $\forall$ coordinate chart $(U,\phi_U)\in\mathcal{A}$, $Df\circ\phi_U^{-1}(\phi_U(p))=0$. However, I don't understand why do we want to define it this way. Why can't we define it simply as $Df(p)=0$? For example, it is possible that $D\phi_U^{-1}$ is the zero map at $\phi_U(p)$, but $Df(p)\neq 0$, and then $Df\circ\phi_U^{-1}(\phi_U(p))=Df(p)\circ D\phi_U^{-1}(\phi_U(p))=0$

Edit: Here’s an example showing that the definitions are not equivalent. Consider $S^2$ and the chart $(U,\phi_U)$, where $U=S^2-\{(0,0,1)\}$ and $\phi_U(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3},\frac{x_2}{1-x_3})$.$\phi^{−1}_U(u,v)=(\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1}, \frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1}, \frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1}).$ Then for $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_3)^2$, $Df\circ\phi^{-1}_U$ is zero at $(0,0)$. This shows that $(0,0,−1)$ is a critical point of $f$ on $S^2$. However, $Df(0,0,−1)=(0,0,−2)\neq 0$

Comment: Doesn't the chart-based definition amount to the definition of "$Df(p) = 0$"? Or if not, could you please edit the question to add the working definition of "$Df(p) = 0$"...? :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I don't see why they are equivalent. Could you please explain why they are equivalent?

Comment: Qualitatively (and a bit loosely, modulo where maps are evaluated), a function $f$ on a manifold has a critical point if and only if _some_ coordinate representation has a critical point, if and only if _every_ coordinate representation has a critical point. <> Because $\phi_U$ is a chart map, its differential is non-singular at each point of $U$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Hmm then is it possible that $D\phi_U^{-1}(\phi_U(p))\neq 0$ and $Df(p)\neq 0$ but $Df\circ \phi_U^{-1}=0$ at $\phi(p)$? For example consider $S^2$ and $(U,\phi_U)$ where $U=S^2-\{(0,0,1)\}$ and $\phi_U(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3},\frac{x_2}{1-x_3})$, then $\phi_U^{-1}(u,v)=(\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1},\frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1},\frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1})$. Then for $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_3)^2$, $Df\circ \phi_U^{-1}$ is zero at $(0,0)$. This shows that $(0,0,-1)$ is a critical point of $f$ on $S^2$. However, $Df(0,0,-1)=(0,0,-2)\neq 0$

Comment: Ah: The height function squared _on the ambient space_ is not the same as the height function squared _on the sphere_. In the context of your question, $f$ is a function on a manifold $M$, and $Df$ must be interpreted as the differential of a function on $M$. <> If that clarifies, please feel free to answer your own question!

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang So the critical point has to be defined this way because of the structure of the manifold, is this what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is unclear if in the class you are taking they defined $Df$ for smooth functions $f$ on $M$. I assume they did and that they verified that for smooth maps of open subsets $f: R^n\to R^m$, $Df$ is given by the "usual" derivative from the vector calculus. I assume also that they proved in the class the **Chain Rule** for maps between differentiable manifolds: If
$$
X \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} Y \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} Z
$$
are smooth maps of smooth manifolds, then for $h=f\circ g$ one has
$$
Dh=Df \circ Dg.
$$
Furthermore, I assume that you verified that local charts $(\phi, U)$ on a smooth manifold are diffeomorphisms between their domains and ranges, in particular, $D\phi^{-1}_q$ is invertible for all $q\in \phi(U)$.

Now, the definition for a critical point of $f\in C^\infty(M)$,
$$
Df_p={\bf 0}
$$
is perfectly reasonable. (Here and below, ${\bf 0}$ stands for the zero map $T_pM\to {\mathbb R}$.) Let's verify that it is equivalent to the definition from your class:

Suppose that $(U, \phi)$ is a chart on $M$, $p\in U, q=\phi(p)$. Then for $g=\phi^{-1}$ and $h=f\circ g$ we have
$$
Dh_q= Df_p \circ Dg_q. 
$$
Since $Dg_q$ is invertible, it follows that
$$
Dh_q\circ (Dg_q)^{-1}= Df_p
$$

The claim then is that $Dh_q$ if and only if $Df_p={\bf 0}$. But this is just a simple linear algebra statement: If $Df_p={\bf 0}$ then $Dh_q={\bf 0}\circ Dg_q={\bf 0}$. If $Dh_q={\bf 0}$ then
$$
{\bf 0}\circ (Dg_q)^{-1}= Df_p \Rightarrow Df_p={\bf 0}. 
$$

Thus, the two definitions of critical points are equivalent.

Comment: Wait then what about the example I gave in the comment?

Comment: @Irene: If you want me to look at it, then you should write it in the body of the question in full detail. As follows from my answer, you have made a mistake somewhere, but to find one one needs all the details.

Comment: The post is edited

Comment: @Irene: I see. You did not finish the computation of $Df$. You have to compute it as a map of the tangent space of the sphere at the south pole. Since the gradient vector you computed is orthogonal to the tangent plane, once you are done with the computation you will get zero.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you